# VMWare Horizon Client does not open when started from launcher

Tags: 16.04, launcher, vmware, unity-dash

When I launch **VMWare Horizon Client** from the Ubuntu sidebar (or the search) the icon flashes multiple times.

But no window is showing up!

When I use terminal and run `vmware-view` everything works fine!

I downloaded the linux (64bit) Setup [here](https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/info/slug/desktop_end_user_computing/vmware_horizon_clients/3_0) and ran it using `sudo bash VMware-Horizon-Client-4.1.0-3976982.x64.bundle`

I am using a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04.1 and have installed all updates (using `apt-get dist-upgrade -y`).

Is there an easy way to fix this?

Comment: I don't know the application, but it will have installed a .desktop file in `/usr/share/applications`. Could you look into the file and see what the command in the (first) `Exec=` is, run it in a terminal window and see what the output is?

Comment: I can't find a .desktop for the application. How can I found out where the .desktop file is when it is pinned to the taskbar? Please read my update above!

Comment: I assumed the application was installed globally, but if not, please look in `~/.local/share/applications`. Not sure if the issue with tv is connected.

Comment: You were right. The shortcut runs `/usr/lib/vmware/view/bin/vmware-view`. `which vmware-view` tells me another path: `/usr/bin/vmware-view`. I will update the path in the shortcut, right?

Comment: Uhm, I don't see a difference? Anyway, since the application is in $PATH, no path is needed to use in the .desktop file.

Comment: Ah sorry, I copied the wrong lines from terminal... I fixed my last comment. After changing the paths (to the one from `which`) it works. The other executable path is missing some libraries. Windows always showed a message box when libraries were missing. I miss that feature in ubuntu!

Comment: Just `vmware-view` should also do. Not sure why the installer used an incorrect line though.