# How to fix "No such file or directory" errorwhen trying to launch VMware Horizon view client

Tags: launcher, vmware

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I downloaded VMware Horizon client from [this link](https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/details?downloadGroup=CART17Q1_LIN64_440&productId=578&rPId=15158). I installed it using the instructions found 
[here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/521199/how-to-install-bundle-packages-in-ubuntu). I am on a 64-bit machine.

1. I right clicked the downloads folder and chose "Open in terminal"
2. I ran the following lines:

   `chmod a+x VMware-Horizon-Client-4.4.0-5167967.x64.bundle
   sudo ./VMware-Horizon-Client-4.4.0-5167967.x64.bundle`

After this, the launcher for the client appears in search, but clicking it only makes it blink several times in the unity bar and then go away. This action is exactly as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/810635/vmware-horizon-client-does-not-open-when-started-from-launcher). In this question, it is described that they are able to launch the client with the command `vmware-view`. I however, receive the following error with `vmware-view`:

> /usr/lib/vmware/view/bin/vmware-view: error while loading shared libraries: libudev.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

[This link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/288821/how-do-i-resolve-a-cannot-open-shared-object-file-libudev-so-0-error) provides some solutions to a `libudev.so.0: cannot open shared object file` error. However, they weren't specific to my problem and I didn't try any of them as I didn't want to risk breaking things.

Why is `VMware-view` not working for me, how can I fix this error? Is it safe for me to go ahead and try the answer with 170+ upvotes by senshikaze?

```
`sudo ln -sf /lib/$(arch)-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1 /lib/$(arch)-linux-gnu/libudev.so.0`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed your description of installing the product and I noticed something worrisome. The last step in the installing is listed here:

```
Do you want to check your system compatibilities for Horizon Client,
this Scan will NOT collect any of your data?[yes/no]: yes

Scanning    libxml2.so.2
    Please wait
[######################################################################] 100%
VMware Horizon Smart Card
    Success
VMware Horizon Real-Time Audio-Video
    Failed      libudev.so.0
VMware Horizon Client Drive Redirection
    Success
VMware Horizon Multimedia Redirection (MMR)
    Failed      libgstapp-0.10.so.0
    Failed      libgstbase-0.10.so.0
    Failed      libgstreamer-0.10.so.0
VMware Horizon PCoIP
    Failed      libffi.so.5
VMware Horizon USB Redirection
    Failed      libudev.so.0
VMware Horizon Virtual Printing
    Success
VMware Horizon Client
    Failed      libudev.so.0
```

Starting the vmware-view command gave me exactly the same error. Using Google I found I had to run this command:

> wget
>   http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/u/udev/libudev0_175-0ubuntu9_amd64.deb

Then I used File Manager in the directory to right-click the downloaded file and let Software Installer do its thing.
Then I gave the command 'vmware-view' and got:

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a link to the page where you found the command?

Comment: http://gamblisfx.com/how-to-solve-missing-libudev-so-0-library-on-ubuntu-16-04/

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't vote you up. I will once I have enough reputation!

Answer (score 0):

This is how i installed 64 bit version 4.7 ... hope this is useful to someone who happens to stumble on it in their searches *(I did not have to install any dependencies or create symbolic links prior to installing successfully)*:

1) Download client from from https://www.vmware.com/go/viewclients

2) Uninstall any previous version (if any).

3)

- a) Open a Terminal window.
- b) Change directories to the directory that contains the installer file (xxx.bundle).

4) Run the installer with the following command:

```
sudo sh ./VMware-Horizon-Client-x.x.x-yyyyyyy.arch.bundle
```

*or in my case:

```
sudo sh ./VMware-Horizon-Client-4.7.0-7395152.x64.bundle
```

(To note: the "sh" is there to "force" the bundle to be executable.. depending on the permissions YOU have set forth this will also work:

```
sudo ./VMware-Horizon-Client-x.x.x-yyyyyyy.arch.bundle
```

5) Follow the Gui install wizard..

Comment: **To note: I received the same error as the original poster @naco when executing the command without the sh.